# How to find my CLR20r3 Exception

Tags: c#, exception

my program crashes, but not on my computer...

```
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: test.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 4.0.4.0
  Problem Signature 03: 4ca51a70
  Problem Signature 04: System.Windows.Forms
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4ba1e14e
  Problem Signature 07: 939
  Problem Signature 08: 17
  Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidOperationException
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

How can I debug this problem or find the location? I think the problem might be threading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does this information come from? You can generate output onto a console for your exception (eg stacktrace) by attaching a handler to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and writing the exception details to `Console.Write`

Comment: It should still output the exception details when it is run from a commandline

Comment: I tried it with a other exception I provoked, but there came only a window with debug informations but no console ouput.

Comment: You could hook into the `Application.UnhandledException` event to print out unhandled exceptions info onto the commandline...

Comment: You mean the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event?

Comment: That's the one. Assign a handler to that on startup & output any exception details to the console.

Comment: Absolutely.  You ought to put that in your answer.

Comment: I hope that will help (can't test it on my pc for that exception) but I included that event and I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your temp directory being filled with scoped_dir(random number) what you need to do is go to %temp% and clear out all of the scoped_dir folders that are left in there.

this can occur due to programs running the CEF engine closing abnormally and not deleting the folders